# Discord js: Selecting a random user from users who posted right answer in a channel

Tags: javascript, discord

This is my first Discord bot and I am stuck.
I want this bot to pick a winner for a quiz.

So, I am trying to fetch all messages with correct answer from a random user.
However the following code does not pick up a user with right answer.

Could you please tell me how I should do this??

```js
       const chan = message.channel;
       const answer = 'test';
   
       //Select a random user
       const user = message.channel.members.random();
       const userid = user.id

      //fetch messages from the user and contains answer
      chan.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
           const usermsgs = messages.filter(
                  m => m.author.id === `${user.id}` &&  
                       m.content === answer);
              
        //check if the answer is in the messages
        if(usermsgs){
            message.reply('winner is' + `${user.user}`);
        }else{
            message.reply('No Winner');
        }
        
      }).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: and what happens when it runs.. any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with discord.js, but a littling reading into their docs came up this.

Instead of randomizing the entire channel's user base, you want to randomize the users who correctly answered the question. Since discord.js returns a Collection object for the filter function, you can use its random function there.

```
chan.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
  const usermsgs = messages.filter(
    m => m.content === answer);

  if(usermsgs){
    const randomCorrectUser = usermsgs.random().author;
    message.reply('winner is' + `${randomCorrectUser.username}`);
  }else{
    message.reply('No Winner');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, I tried this and this works. Also, could you guide me how to post username without '@' so that I can test this... Currently, if I do this, mentions go to the picked users....

Comment: Unfortunately, that is going beyond the scope of my limited knowledge with discord.js

Answer (score 0):

Uhh this is old but you could probably do 
`const randomCorrectUser = usermsgs.random().author.tag;`
for name#0000 or 
`const randomCorrectUser = usermsgs.random().author.username;` 
for just the name